# adding Or updating Modified Date attribute in AppSync using VTL

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, vtl

I am working on AppSync,I am struggling on how to save date in Dynamo Db using VTL. My actual requirement is to save the date when the API is called. Please let me know how to achieve this using Date.now() in Dynamo Db. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replied in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625805/how-to-add-current-date-in-putitem-in-vtl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Current Date in putItem in VTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625805/how-to-add-current-date-in-putitem-in-vtl)

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this using `$util.time.nowEpochSeconds()`

e.g :

```
#set($input={})
$util.qr($input.put("createdAt", $util.time.nowEpochSeconds()))
$util.qr($input.put("updatedAt", $util.time.nowEpochSeconds()))

#set($id=$util.autoId())

{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("$id")
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($input)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, using DynamoDb for example you can add the attribute before mapping it:

```
$util.qr($ctx.args.input.put("createdAt", $util.time.nowISO8601()))

{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
  },
  "attributeValues": $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input),
  "condition": {
    "expression": "attribute_not_exists(#id)",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#id": "id",
    },
  },
}
```

Format options:

```
$util.time.nowISO8601()                                            : 2018-02-06T19:01:35.749Z
$util.time.nowEpochSeconds()                                       : 1517943695
$util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds()                                  : 1517943695750
$util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")                    : 2018-02-06 19:01:35+0000
$util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ", "+08:00")          : 2018-02-07 03:01:35+0800
$util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ", "Australia/Perth") : 2018-02-07 03:01:35+0800
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html