# How to add Current Date in putItem in VTL

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
    "createdDate":$core_v2_utility.CurrentDate
  },
  "attributeValues": $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input),
  "condition": {
    "expression": "attribute_not_exists(#id)",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#id": "id",
      "#createdDate":"createdDate",
    },
   },
}
```

I have been trying to add a createDate into DynamoDB using VTL.I am finding error with $core_v2_utility.CurrentDate

Answer (score 1):

AWS AppSync does not have a `$core_v2_utility.CurrentDate`. Did you mean to use one of the [time helpers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html#time-helpers-in-util-time)? `$util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")` gives you the current date and time in UTC.